# Rational Function Theorem related to Integration?

Tags: analysis

I know how to use this algorithm when I am integrating rational functions, but my textbook has omitted the actual proof for why it works. If someone could please help me with this question:
[image]

Comment: Multiply the equation by $(x-1)^2$ then solve for $c_{1,2}$. After clearing denominators, partial fraction decomposition is reduced to linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{c_1}{x-1}+\frac{c_2}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{c_1(x-1)+c_2}{(x-1)^2}$. Equating coefficients in $c_1x+(c_2-c_1)=c_1(x-1)+c_2=ax+b$ gives $c_1=a$ and $c_2-c_1=b$ so that $c_2=a+b$.

Comment: Would this be considered a proof, I never know if something is considered "rigorous" or not?